# How i do execute sqlite in iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite

I have the following problem. An application that has a sqlite database. I run the application in xcode, with the simulator. I have the following code to know where I have to put the database.

sqlite3 *bd;

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *dbPath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bd.sqlite"];

NSLog(@"La ruta de la base de Datos es ---- %@",dbPath);
```

So I get the path, and copy the sqlite database, so the application works perfectly in xcode.
The problem is when I connect my iphone and try to run the application. Because the previous code gives me a route on the iphone, and I try to put the sqlite database there but it does not run, the application is blocked because it cannot find the database, even if I put it there. I don't know if what I am doing is correct or there is another way to do it. I'm going crazy looking for possible solutions on the internet, but none works for me and I've been standing for 3 months trying to run the application on the iphone. Please, some help or advice, I would appreciate it. Many thanks.

Comment: The database won't be in your Documents folder. Assuming you package the file with your app, it will start in the app bundle. You need to copy it from the app bundle to the Documents folder on app startup if needed (and only if you need to write to the database).

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. but I have the doubt, the documents folder but the mac or iphone ?. I use the database to read data that is then displayed in a table. Thank you

Comment: I'm referring to the Documents folder on the iOS device which is what your code is trying to access. That's not where the file will be. It will be in your app bundle. Inglés por favor.

Comment: note: the database is inside the application folder.

Comment: Forgive my awkwardness. I am very new to this and likewise my questions are poorly formulated.
If I have the sqlite database on the mac and it works perfectly for me, my question is where I have to put the database on the iphone so that, when the application needs it, I can read from it. In the code that I have put, it tells me where the database should be on the iphone so that the application can access, but when I access that route there is no such folder and I have to create it by hand, once I create it hand, I copy the sqlite database